# Browser history javascript object stack limit

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, webkit

I have a PhoneGap app we are running which starts out on a local index page on the device.  That page detects to see if our server is up before redirecting to our remote application pages.  We have a scenario where someone can be browsing our app like normal but then lose the internet connection, in this case I would like to go back to the original page they started at in the "history" object's browser history stack (the one they started on the local device).  Is the first entry in the stack guarenteed to be the very first page the user visited, or does the stack cap out at a maximum amount of pages?  Or is there any way that the stack could be cleared?

I'm thinking of doing something like history.go(-1 * stacksize).

Comment: You could use the event listener `offline` and then instead of checking the stack, directly set the location to the local file.

Comment: You can't set the location to the local file from a remote page.